# How do you find the nth node in a binary tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic, binary-tree, tree-traversal

I want to find the nth node/element in a binary tree. Not the nth largest/smallest, just the nth in inorder order for example.

How would this be done? Is it possible to keep it to one function? Many functions employ an external variable to keep track of the iterations outside of the recursion, but that seems... lazy, for lack of a better term.

Comment: I feel like you answered your own question. Are you asking how to do a inorder traversal iteratively?

Comment: @tachyonflux I'm not sure how I answered my own question. I can traverse with inorder, but it's not clear how to say, "return me the 10th node in the inorder traversal". I'm not sure how to stop at the nth specified node and return it.

Comment: Suppose your tree is ordered using a classic `<` order relationship. How can the n-th node in inorder traversal be different than the n-th smallest node ? Then, I guess your tree isn't ordered, is it ?

Comment: You could combine your tree with a linked list (a pointer to the "successor" node in each node). You'll have to update the insertion and deletion algorithm to keep these references up to date. On the side, keep a reference to the first element, just like you do with the root.

Answer (score 4):

You can augment the binary search tree into an [order statistic tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree), which supports a "return the nth element" operation

Edit: If you just want the ith element of an inorder traversal (instead of the ith smallest element) and don't want to use external variables then you can do something like the following:

```
class Node {
  Node left
  Node right
  int data
}

class IterationData {
  int returnVal
  int iterationCount
}

IterationData findNth(Node node, IterationData data, int n) {
  if(node.left != null) {
    data = findNth(node.left, data, n)
  }
  if(data.iterationCount < n) {
    data.iterationCount++
    if(data.iterationCount == n) {
      data.returnVal = node.data
      return data
    } else if(node.right != null) {
      return findNth(node.right, data, n)
    } else {
      return data
    }
  }
}
```

You'll need some way to return two values, one for the iteration count and one for the return value once the nth node is found; I've used a class, but if your tree contains integers then you could use an integer array with two elements instead.

Comment: Creating a new tree isn't optimal in this case.

Comment: It looks like it's not a new tree, just a new function

Answer (score 2):

In order iterative traversal, keep track of nodes passed in external variable.

```
public static Node inOrderInterativeGet(Node root, int which){
    Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<Node>();
    Node current = root;
    boolean done = false;
    int i = 1;

    if(which <= 0){
        return null;
    }

    while(!done){
        if(current != null){
            stack.push(current);
            current = current.getLeft();
        }
        else{
            if(stack.empty()){
                done = true;
            }
            else{
                current = stack.pop();

                if(i == which){
                    return current;
                }
                i++;

                current = current.getRight();
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to have a size property which is left_subtree + right_subtree + 1:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, data=None, left=None, right=None,
                 size=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.size = size


def select(node, k):
  """Returns node with k-th position in-order traversal."""
  if not node:
    return None

  t = node.left.size if node.left else 0
  if t > k:
    return select(node.left, k)
  elif t < k:
    return select(node.right, k - t - 1)
  else:
    return node
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like global variable, pass to recursive function additional parameter - some int variable, let's call it `auto_increment` or just `ai`. `ai` stores order of current node. Also, recursive function should return maximal value of `ai` of current vertex subtree,because after visiting whole subtree next 'free' value will be `max_ai_in_subreee+1` Something like that

```
int rec(int vertex,int ai){
   traverseOrder[vertex] = ai
   if(getChildren(vertex)!=null) return ai;
   else{
     for(childrens){
         ai = rec(child,ai+1);
     }
     return ai;// subtree visited, return maximal free value upstairs.
   }
}
```

If your function already returns some useful data, it may return some complex object which contains `{useful data+ai}`

Start from some vertex looks like `rec(start_vertex,1);`

Answer (score 0):

Below is full code that you can use to find the nth element using inorder in a Binary Tree.

```
public class NthNodeInInoeder {

    static public class Tree {

        public int data;
        public Tree left,right;

        public Tree(int data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    static Tree root;
    static int count = 0;

    private static void inorder(Tree root2, int num) {

        if (root2 == null)
            return;
        Tree node = root2;
        Stack<Tree> stack = new Stack<>();

        while (node != null || stack.size() > 0) {
            while (node != null) {
                stack.push(node);
                node = node.left;
            }

            node = stack.pop();
            count++;
            if (count == num) {
                System.out.println(node.data);
                break;
            }
            node = node.right;

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        root = new Tree(10);
        root.left = new Tree(20);
        root.right = new Tree(30);
        root.left.left = new Tree(40);
        root.left.right = new Tree(50);
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        inorder(root, num);
        sc.close();

    }

}
```